# How to code a swivel type animation on a textbox in C# without using markup

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I saw an example on how to create a glow effect when the image gets focus in mark-up. 
Below is the C# code example i found that uses double animation for opacity of a rectangle, i need to perform a glow or swivel effect using C# and not markup since i am not comfortable with it.

```
        DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        myDoubleAnimation.From = 1.0;
        myDoubleAnimation.To = 0.0;
        myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        myDoubleAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
        myDoubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

        myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        myStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, myRectangle.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.OpacityProperty));
```

Comment: I think you are missing out by not dedicating the time to learn xaml, and I'm also not exactly sure why you would bother with WPF at all if you don't plan on becoming comfortable with it.

Comment: Currently, i am not but i will eventually, right now i just want to do this for a project i am working on needs to be submitted next week. I am new to C# and WPF development.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your Main(), after InitializeComponent();

```
textBlock1.Text = "Mouse over me";

var effect = new DropShadowEffect();
effect.Color = Colors.Red;
effect.BlurRadius = 10d;
effect.Opacity = 0d;
effect.ShadowDepth = 0d;
textBlock1.Effect = effect;

textBlock1.MouseEnter += (s, e) => {
    var anim = new DoubleAnimation(0d, 1d, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
    effect.BeginAnimation(DropShadowEffect.OpacityProperty, anim); };

textBlock1.MouseLeave += (s, e) => {
    var anim = new DoubleAnimation(1d, 0d, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
    effect.BeginAnimation(DropShadowEffect.OpacityProperty, anim); };
```

But I'd suggest stop wasting time with C# for GUI code, XAML is so much more convenient.